# Unit Test - Invalid Operation Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

My ***Unit Test*** is returning an error stating: `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element.`

When I start debugging, it automatically stops my debugger after hitting `var result = _forgotPass.SendEmail(...);` Why is it throwing this exception
and how can I fix this issue?

**Error:** `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element.`

**Unit Test:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void SendEmail()
{
    //Arrange
    _getUrl.Setup(mock => mock.AddUrlLink(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new ApiResponse<Status, string>(Status.Success, "link"));
    _emailMock.Setup(mock => mock.Send(It.IsAny<CarrierModel>())).Returns(new ApiResponse<bool, string>(false, ""));

    //Act
    var result = _forgotPass.SendEmail("myemail@gmail.com");

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(Status.EmailFailed, result.Status);
    Assert.IsNull(result.Body);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Messages.Any(m => m == "Email Failed"));
}
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with your exception? The line you've indicated is presumably your code and I would assume that somewhere in there this exception is being thrown. At a guess that looks like using a call to `Single`() on an empty enumerable but impossible to say for sure with just the code you've given.

Comment: what's happening in _forgotPass.SendEmail? "Sequence contains no matching element" means your calling something like First() or Single() on a collection with 0 elements.

Comment: @Chris there isn't a `stack trace` to go with the exception.

Comment: The error looks like an ICollection error, maybe with your Linq calls.

You sure you are not in Release instead of Debug mode? That could explain the debugger to show wrong line.

Comment: @jlevet just checked and I am still using the **debug mode**

Comment: could you post the code inside SendEmail function?